# Does $X^A = Y^B \Longrightarrow X=Y \wedge A=B$? (ETCS)

Tags: category-theory, alternative-set-theories

I'm trying to prove that $f^\flat$ is well-defined, where $f^\flat:Z\times A \to X$ is defined to be the composition $e_X \circ 1\times f$ where $1\times f: A\times Z \to A\times X^A$ and $e_X: A\times X^A \to X$ but I'm not sure how to prove equality of sets (well I suppose $1$ being a terminal object induces a unique map $\beta_S$ for every set $S$, so that two sets, $S$ and $T$, are equal if $\beta_S=\beta_T$ but I'm not sure that's helpful).

Notice in particular, if $X^A = Y^B$ but $X\neq Y \vee A\neq B$ then $f^\flat$ is not well-defined.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $=$ here? Do you mean that the two sets are isomorphic (i.e. there is a bijection between them), or do you mean that the there is an isomorphism which respects the elements, i.e. mapping each $f\colon A\to X$ to a unique $g\colon B\to Y$?

Comment: What’s $f$? And do you mean the map $f\mapsto f^\flat$ or the map $f^\flat$ might not be well defined?

Comment: I mean that $f\mapsto ^♭$ might not be well-defined since it seems to depend on the choice of the evaluation map which is sensitive to the underlying sets (in the exponential set $X^A$)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, this statement is false. Category theory usually has a hard time dealing with *equality* since categorical constructions are typically done up to isomorphism (in this specific instance, the exponential object $X^A$ is formally defined as the universal set endowed with an evaluation map $X^A\times A\to X$ and is thus only unique up to unique isomorphism).

In this case, it is possible for $X^A=Y^B$ without $X=Y$ or $A=B$ (it can even be neither): if $X=Y=*$ is the terminal object, then $X^A=Y^B$ for any $A$ and $B$; conversely, if $A=B=\varnothing$ is the initial object, then $X^A=Y^B$ for any $X$ and $Y$. Combining the two, you can have $X^A=Y^B$ with $X\neq Y$ *and* $A\neq B$ (for instance, $\{0,1\}^\varnothing=\{0\}^{\{0\}}$ are both singletons).

Even if you pick your favourite canonical set $X^A$ (for instance, taking $X^A := \{f\subseteq A\times X \mid \forall a\in A,\exists!x\in X,(a,x)\in f\}$) the statement will still be false just by taking $A=B=\varnothing$ since $X^A=Y^B=\{\varnothing\}$ for any $X,Y$.

Comment: Those are very good examples, using the initial and final objects.  So does this mean that $f^\flat$ is not well-defined?

Comment: I'm not sure what $f^\flat$ is... correct me if I'm wrong: given a map $f:Z\to X^A$, you define $f^\flat:Z\times A\to X$ to be the composite $Z\times A\xrightarrow{(f,\operatorname{id}_A)}X^A\times A\xrightarrow{\operatorname{ev}_A}X$? This map is certainly well-defined, but I'm not sure what purpose it serves.

Comment: Yes, but isn't $ev_A$ sensitive to the representation of $X^A$.  Sorry, I'm fairly new to category theory.

Comment: it is; more precisely, it is _provided with_ the definition of $X^A$: to define $X^A$ as an exponential object is to come up with a set (called $X^A$) and a map $\operatorname{ev}_A:X^A\times A\to X$ then subject to a universality condition.

Comment: In other words, the evaluation map is fixed once you fix your choice of $X^A$.

Comment: But that is precisely my issue.  Suppose that $f: Z \to X^A$ and $X^A=Y^B$ then which evaluation map constructs $f^\flat$?

Comment: Ah, this is where a bit of nuance comes into play. The nature of your mapping $f\mapsto f^\flat$ requires that you specify that $f$ is mapping into $X^A$ _or_ $Y^B$ (i.e., you have to specify which exponential object you're looking at), or else there's no way of knowing what the domain and codomain of $f^\flat$ ought to be. Perhaps this answers your question, in a way, since you can interpret this as saying: "$f\mapsto f^\flat$ is not well defined if you view $X^A$ only as a set"